# Inconsistently receiving FORCE_DEPLOY error when Deploying app via jenkins on wildfly 10

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, amazon-ec2, wildfly

When I try to run maven "clean compile install wildfly:deploy" on jenkins for my application, it works fine sometimes and returns a success but sometimes it fails with the below error. The application code did not change but the behavior of the build keeps changing. I did try to restart the wildfly server manually on Amazon Linux ec2 instance to see that it sometimes helps. The same mvn works fine locally when testing the app and deploying on local windows workstation.

NOTE: My Jenkins and Wildfly app server are on the same Amazon Linux EC2 instance. So on the build script, I referred it as localhost.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha7:deploy (default-cli) on project MedDRA-DataProcessing: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Operation was cancelled -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha7:deploy (default-cli) on project MedDRA-DataProcessing: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.wildfly.plugin.common.DeploymentExecutionException: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.executeDeployment(AbstractDeployment.java:147)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.doExecute(AbstractDeployment.java:179)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractAppDeployment.doExecute(AbstractAppDeployment.java:70)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Operation was cancelled
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:149)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:80)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:153)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Operation was cancelled
        at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.operationCancelled(AsyncFutureTask.java:70)
        at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:267)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractDelegatingAsyncFuture.get(AbstractDelegatingAsyncFuture.java:57)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:147)
        ... 28 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

pom.xml has:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Deployment on AS from console -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven.wildfly}</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <port>9990</port>
                <username>user1</username>
                <password>password1</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the operation might be timing out. Could you try turning on debug logging on the server for `org.jboss.as.protocol`? Also check the server logs to see if there is anything interesting. Here's a CLI command to turn on debug logging. `/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.protocol:add(level=TRACE)`. That should log to the server.log by default.

Comment: Another possibility is the network may be getting interrupted which would close the client and cancel the deploy operation.

Comment: I was able to duplicate this by prematurely closing the client connection so I think this is likely an environmental issue. Something must be closing the channel the client is communicating on.

Comment: James, I shall try your recommendations and share my observations.

Comment: James, this setup is on AWS cloud and i think most likely it is a environment thing. Is it possible that having jenkins build server, wildfly on the same server could be causing it ?

How were you able to replicate it locally ? What do you mean by prematurely closing the client connection ? were you trying to close it prematurely in a programmatical fashion ?

Comment: I just wrote a quick program to open a connection, execute an operation asynchronously, close the connection then try to get the result of the future. I'd say it's likely an environmental thing.

Comment: I am having the same error now. Can anyone tell me the solution and cause of this error. It is occuring when i include some extra resource file like json . Without those extra resource simple war would deploy normally.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use other plugin versions then alpha for your plugins? I recommend final versions as it often happes that there can be inconsistencies in alphabuilds

Comment: Thanks Merkel for responding. I did try with 1.0.2.Final wildfly plugin and the behavior remained inconsistent with it as well. It shows the same error.

Comment: Yes, latest version is not solving this issue